# Can I post queries related to a specific software in ServerFault?

Tags: discussion

I have read in the FAQ section that

> Server Fault is not for general
>   computer troubleshooting questions; if
>   you paid for that desktop hardware,
>   and it's your personal workstation, it
>   is unlikely that your question is
>   appropriate for Server Fault.

So my question is ***can I post a particular software related queries in this site***. Suppose I have a problem with one of the sofwares and if I contact the official support forum for the software it might take days to resolve the problem. So posting in a site like serverfault which has a wide range of users can solve the issue in a shorter period. Is this appropriate or not.

Answer (score 3):

I'm fairly sure it depends on the software in question, and the nature of the query.

If you can't figure out how to change your screensaver in Windows XP, that's for SuperUser.

If you can'f figure out how to set a GPO to change a screensaver, that's for us.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [SuperUser.com](https://superuser.com/questions) if you have non-Admin related software questions.  It will be out of beta soon.

Comment: Just find the password on blog.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2):

Have you also read this section in the FAQ ?

> Also, try to refrain from asking questions about **Server Fault** itself unless you absolutely, positively have to. Most admins don't come here to learn about the intricacies of this site; they come here to get answers to their questions. Let's try to help them out by not cluttering up the system with navelgazing meta-discussion. If you want to suggest a feature or discuss how **Server Fault** works, visit our [meta-discussion site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Is this software something that you support for multiple users as part of your job? If yes, then the question is probably appropiate for stackoverflow, if not it's probably better off on [superuser.com](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/super-user-semi-private-beta-begins/)

Answer (score 0):

If your question is related to database software or the like it would be appropriate for ServerFault.

You will probably want to post your question on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com).  It is a more general computer support Question and Answer site.