# Why did this question get deleted?

Tags: support, status-completed, deleted-questions, 10k

I got back from vacation and saw I had a Teacher badge for [this question](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/46/can-i-post-queries-related-to-a-specific-software-in-serverfault/47#47), but when I went to look at the question it had disappeared.  Can some 10k please tell me why this question was deleted?  I'm a 10k on MetaSO, but here I'm pretty helpless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really sure why that got deleted.  Looks like it might have just been a mistake.  I undeleted the question.

Answer (score 3):

[Jeff](https://meta.serverfault.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) deleted it.  I am not entirely sure why.